# Regular Expression for word occurence in a text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to count the occurrence of a word inside a text

```
string term="framework";
int count = Regex.Matches(r.ResourceDescription.ToLower(), "\b" + term + "\b/gm").Count;
```

but on the following text (contained in r.ResourceDescription) it returns alway 0:

"Markets play a paramount role in enhancing people's livelihoods and promoting food security. BE tailored a food security framework having markets as one of the elements that should be tackled within the overall food security analysis."

Comment: Get rid of the `/gm`.  And you can use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` instead of `ToLower`

Comment: @juharr yes already tested...but nothing change. The count is always 0

Comment: As other's have noticed you also have to escape the backslashes either `"\\b"` or `@"\b"`.  the second one is called a verbatim string.

Comment: You need to escape by "\\" IMO, i.e.`"\\b" + term + "\\b/gm"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you were creating a pattern, you forgot to escape string. So, try like this:

```
string desc = "Markets play a paramount role in enhancing people's livelihoods and promoting food security. BE tailored a food security framework having markets as one of the elements that should be tackled within the overall food security analysis";
string term = "framework";
string regex = @"\b" + term + @"\b";
int count = Regex.Matches(desc, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```